# How to get correct current video settings for DJI Drone using DJI Android SDK

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I need to get the currently set video resolution for the camera live stream on a DJI Drone. I have attempted to get it through [DJICodecManager](https://developer.dji.com/iframe/mobile-sdk-doc/android/reference/dji/sdk/Codec/DJICodecManager.html), however it returns inconsistent results.

```
val codecManager = DJICodecManager(
      this@MainActivity,
      null,
      0,
      0,
      UsbAccessoryService.VideoStreamSource.Camera
)

val width = codecManager.videoWidth
val height = codecManager.videoHeight
```

Sometimes the videoWidth and videoHeight values return the aspect ratio values (16 and 9) and sometimes it returns the video width and height correctly (1280 and 720).

I haven't found any other way in the documentation. Does anyone know a reliable way to get the currently set video height and width values from a DJI drone?

Thanks.

eg.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give more info. Is it the livestream you're after or do you want to change the recorded resolution?

You have to send data to the codec with sendDataToDecoder().

Have a look at the dji example on github.